# Delphi XE/Windows7: why do VCL controls look different in an MDI application?

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE / Windows 7.

Create a new VCL application, put a TCombobox on your form.

Create a new MDI application, do the same thing.

Why do the controls look different and how can I solve?

Other controls behave the same way. The same thing happens when I place controls on my mdi child forms in the MDI application.

[image: MDI Application][image]

Comment: I don't think that these controls do look different. Could you show screenshots.

Comment: You are referring to the raised effect on the drop down button?

Comment: Obviously the second combo box is themed, while the first isn't.

Comment: Indeed, they look different. Why are they not themed in the MDI application and how can I resolve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MDI application template in XE (and earlier versions) has runtime themes disabled. Simply enable it in the project options to resolve the difference.

This setting in the MDI application template was modified in XE2.

Comment: Thank you David. I enabled this in an existing project and it works but only for newly added components. The existing components remain the same. Any workaround for that?

Comment: That's just a design time thing in the IDE. No probs when you run the program. Anyway, bring the IDE up to date by reopening the project. That's all it takes. I guess you just need the IDE to go round the loop of recreating the windows.

Comment: That is not working David.When I add a combobox to an existing project, I see it as a themed control. All the controls that were already present remain non themed. When I re-open the project or compile it, things stay the same. Tried restarting the IDE but that didn't work either.

Comment: Worked fine here. I think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: If it's a design time thing restricted to the IDE the compiled version should only have themed controls. It has themed and non-themed controls so enabling runtime themes at the project level is not the solution to the question asked. But thank you anyway David.

Comment: No, I answered the question you asked. Which is described creating a new project and adding controls. You appear to want a solution to your problem with you particular project. But that's not what was in the question that was asked.

Comment: You mean you want help with your specific problem? If so then I personally cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Your solution works on a new project so you answered the question David. Again thank you and no offence.It does not seem to work on an existing project and I understand that this does not fit within the question that I asked.

Comment: I'd guess the specifics of your project are the key.